# Deep Q - Learning Exploration - BestQ Value

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to implement a Deep Q - Network to play Asteroids. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to calculate the Q Value exactly if I am exploring. For example, the Agent is exploring for 1 second (otherwise makes no sense; I cannot let it just explore one step), then, of course, it could have done 0.3s  something really good. Unfortunately, it makes a mistake at 0.99s and the reward collapses.

I use at the moment the following formula to evaluate the Q - Value:

$Q_{new,t} = reward + \gamma Q_{max,t+1}$

But how do I know the max Q Value of the next step? I could consider the best Q - Value the network says, but this is not necessarily true.

Edit: You can see the implementation as far (poorly written) here:
https://github.com/SuchtyTV/RLearningBird/blob/master/src/main/java/rlgame/Brain.java

Comment: See: [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/7290).

Comment: Why do you need to know Q-value for the next step? According to the formula you need only Q max in time t